# Wordpress Issue: Sidebar is allowing for link to expand into the footer

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I am not sure how to phrase this as it is boggling my mind. I have a sidebar widget that is setup to show some

images and a link. It has a div and it is closed within the actual widget.

Below I am pasting the actual code I can see when I inspect the element via Chrome.

```
</a><li><a href="/socialmedia/"><img src="/wp-content/themes/newscast/images/skin1/socialside.jpg" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1; "></a></li><a href="/socialmedia/">
            </a></ul><a href="/socialmedia/">
        </a></div><a href="/socialmedia/"></a></div><a href="/socialmedia/">
    </a></div><a href="/socialmedia/"></a></div><a href="/socialmedia/">    
        </a></div><a href="/socialmedia/"></a></div>
```

The first line of code is below and that is in the widget

```
<li><a href="/socialmedia/"><img src="/wp-content/themes/newscast/images/skin1/socialside.jpg" style="visibility: visible; opacity: 1; "></a></li><a href="/socialmedia/">
            </a></ul></div>
```

The code below is being added somehow and I am completely inept of figuring out why haha

```
<a href="/socialmedia/">
        </a></div><a href="/socialmedia/"></a></div><a href="/socialmedia/">
    </a></div><a href="/socialmedia/"></a></div><a href="/socialmedia/">    
        </a></div><a href="/socialmedia/"></a></div>
```

Have a look at the Sidebar on the right and then hover over the footer below. The entire footer is getting the link somehow.

Now what makes this harder, for me, to figure out is if I remove the widget that is calling this sidebar it works fine. The 1st widget, the links, works fine and does not give out any links to anywhere else

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More than likely you are not closing your `<a>` tags in the text widget, so the browser is trying to close them for you by guessing.

Check the text widget and make sure you have a `</a>` for every `<a>` tag.